# hasAttribute not dynamically changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm currently using jQuery Validator on a form of mine, when submitting my form it appears that the `checked` attribute isn't changing on my validator regardless of checked or unchecked.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="platform" value="P1">
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/platform1.png') }}" style="height: 100px;">
            </div>
            <h6>Platform 1</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="platform" value="P2">
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/platform2.png') }}" style="height: 100px;">
            </div>
            <h6>Platform2</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label for="platform" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
</div>
```

Here's my JS:

```
// Code for the Validator
var $validator = $('.wizard-card form').validate({
    rules: {
        platform: {
            required: function () {
                var checked = false;
                $('input[name="platform"]').each(function() {
                    if(jQuery(this)[0].hasAttribute('checked')) {
                        var checked = true;
                    }
                });
                console.log(checked);
                return checked;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I've even tried just using `return $('[name="platform"]:checked').length > 0;` to no avail.

Comment: You are REALLY making a simple thing VERY complicated!  Working demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/7h0kcy7g/

Comment: @Sparky I'm also using the following plugins: http://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard & https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-bootstrap-wizard, your 'demo' doesn't work when these are active

Comment: You're not understanding how these things are supposed to work together, nor have you properly written your question since you failed to mention these other plugins.  Search the SO tag for jQuery Validate to get some clues about how to properly integrate Bootstrap.

Comment: No matter what, you should never need to write a custom `required` function that checks attributes... that's just ridiculous and practically negates the whole point of using the validation plugin.

Comment: Curtis: Sorry to say this so rudely *(if that is rude, it's just the thruth in my opinion...)*: It doesn't look like you have enough knowledge to write a custom rule for `.validate()`. Scope mistake, wrong way to get the checked state, the usage of `jQuery(this)[0]` instead of only `this`... That all indicates you just don't really know what you're doing. **Read the documentation of the plugins you are using** is the right first step in any way.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Maybe you are over-complicating the task here...

That simple rule is supposed to work:

```js
$('.wizard-card form').validate({
  rules: {
    platform: "required"
  }
});
```

```css
.error{
  outline:3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<div class="wizard-card">
  <form>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio">
          <input type="radio" name="platform" value="P1">
          <div class="icon">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="height: 100px;">
          </div>
          <h6>Platform 1</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio">
          <input type="radio" name="platform" value="P2">
          <div class="icon">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="height: 100px;">
          </div>
          <h6>Platform2</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <label for="platform" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
    </div>
    <button id="done">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I suggest you read [the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) a bit more closely.

Comment: It still appears to be behaving the same as my post, my **console log** keeps showing `true` regardless of the `checked` state

Comment: mmm... Okay. Remove the `var` in the `.each()` loop. Redeclaring the variable there makes its scope restrained to the `.each()` function.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use the variables `jQuery` **and** `$` ? I mean: are you sure they both hold the jQuery library as a function? If there is no reason... use `$` everywhere.

Comment: It still doesn't appear to be working, I'll just give it a miss & try find another solution.

Comment: @Curtis, it's working perfectly fine both in the answer above and in this jsFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/7h0kcy7g/